# Extending CSS classes

Tags: html, css

Is there any possibility to extend exists class using only css?

```
.darkStyle {
       color:#eee;
       background:#222;
 }
.element {

       // here I want to get all properties from darkStyle

       min-width:100px;
       display:block;
}
```

I know that i can use in HTML class="darkStyle element" but any extend method like in my example will be more usable.

Comment: @ProgramFOX AFAIK CSS inheritance is a mechanism applying to descendant elements, not to the very same element styled by a previous rule. An element doesn't inherit styles applying to itself, they're just its styles, those that apply to it.

Comment: @FelipeAls Answers to the question I linked can be reused here, so it is a duplicate. For example, the LESS answer there explains exactly what the OP here wants.

Comment: @ProgramFOX The accepted answer also answers the question (partially, there are many other ways). I'm as confused as Jawad there: inheritance (title of alleged duplicate) is a pillar of CSS and doesn't mean this at all in this context

Comment: @FelipeAls The title of the question might be confusing; but the questions basically ask the same thing, and the answers apply here too, so it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) for that.

In Less:

```
.element {
   .darkStyle; // Will output all styles from .darkStyle;
   min-width:100px;
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: Also, the actual answer to the actual question is "no, not using _only_ CSS".

Answer (score 1):

Assign the common properties first, then assign the unique properties for .element. This would be the only way with CSS only. You can use CSS frameworks like Less for added features like inheritance.

```
.darkStyle, .element {
    color:#eee;
    background:#222;
}

.element {
   min-width:100px;
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: This is a good point on managing CSS, but does illustrate any way to actually _extend_ a class using _pure_ CSS (not possible).

Comment: Yes, of course you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't "extend" classes. And you don't need to, CSS isn't a programming OO language and has different mechanisms.

For example, classes can be combined on a given HTML element:

```
<p class="darkStyle">
  I'm styled by styles applying to .darkStyle
</p>
<p class="darkStyle element">
  I'm styled by styles applying to both .darkStyle and .element
</p>
```

[Multiclass!](http://www.lambopower.com/forum/uploads/monthly_04_2013/post-6125-1365865162.jpg)

Comment: Although possible, I think this kind of CSS markup is not the best. Design should be kept out of HTML as much as possible. Better to combine in the CSS itself I think.

Comment: @Pierre-EmmanuelLevesque There's no CSS in my answer, only the classes used by OP. Though in an ideal world, there'd be perfect separation of content and form in huge projects it just doesn't scale. New template, more CSS rules, repeat ad lib and obtain thousands of CSS rules. OOCSS and such are very very useful methodologies in these cases

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I meant to say I don't think having CSS hooks of this kind in your HTML is a good idea. I would say it's actually harder to scale like that, not easier. The more you separate content and design the easier scaling will be in my opinion. Personal preference I guess.